# How to make String between characters to * like te***t in android?

Tags: android

I want String between characters to ** like Te**t. Below mentioned code i am using but it is not working. Kindly check whether i am doing in right way or not

```
    fun changeName(getName: String?) {
    var name = getName
    when (getName?.length) {
        2 -> {
            for (i in getName.indices) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    name += "*"
                } else {
                    name += getName[i]
                }
            }
            name += "*"
        }
        3 -> {
            for (i in getName.indices) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    name += "*"
                } else {
                    name += getName[i]
                }
            }
        }
        else -> {
            for (i in getName!!.indices) {
                if (i != 0 && i != getName.length - 1) {
                    name += "*"
                } else {
                    name += getName[i]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want results like this A*****d..?

Comment: Yes the same way i want result

Answer (score 1):

Your function is working fine. You just have to return the name String to use it. Like this

```
fun changeName(getName: String?) :String{
//when statement
  return name
}
```